# Why isn't the EventListener registering that a button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

The problem is that the EventListener is not detecting anything.

Here is the code:

```js
// Starts after the html document is completely loaded and ready to go
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Importing all the elements
  const inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");
  const textArea = document.getElementById("list-field");
  const returnButton = document.getElementById("button-input");
  const suggestionsContainer = document.querySelector(
    ".autocomplete-suggestions"
  );
  const priceH1 = document.getElementById("price-h1");
  const priceH1Child = priceH1.querySelector("span");
  const applyChangesButton = document.getElementById("apply-changes");
  const allCheckbox = document.getElementById("all");
  const dropdownOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content a");

  // Getting data from .csv file based on checkboxes
  let csvFiles = [];

  // Create an array of fetch promises
  let fetchPromises = csvFiles.map((url) =>
    fetch(url).then((response) => response.text())
  );

  // Dropdown menu value
  let selectedValue;
  dropdownOptions.forEach((option) => {
    option.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      selectedValue = this.getAttribute("data-value");
    });
  });

  // Listens for Select All checkbox to be checked
  allCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    checkAll();
  });

  // Calling applyChanges() function after pressing the button
  applyChangesButton.addEventListener("click", async function(event) {
    applyChanges();
    console.log(csvFiles);

    try {

      // Use Promise.all() to fetch all the files concurrently
      const dataArray = await Promise.all(fetchPromises);
      const combinedData = dataArray.join("\n"); // Combine the CSV data from multiple files
      const autocompleteData = parseCSVData(combinedData);

      // Showing autocomplete suggestions
      inputField.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        const inputText = removeDiacritics(this.value);
        const suggestions = getAutocompleteSuggestions(
          inputText,
          autocompleteData
        );

        // Rendering the suggestions
        renderSuggestions(suggestions);
      });

      // After clicking on a suggestion, it is added to a text area, and the input is cleared
      var totalPrice = 0;
      suggestionsContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains("autocomplete-suggestion")) {
          const selectedSuggestion = event.target.innerText;
          const currentText = textArea.value;

          if (currentText.includes(selectedSuggestion)) {
            return; // Skip adding duplicate suggestion
          }
          const newText = currentText ?
            currentText + "\n" + selectedSuggestion :
            selectedSuggestion;
          textArea.value = newText;
          suggestionsContainer.innerHTML = "";
          inputField.value = "";

          // Adding up price
          const newestText = textArea.value;
          const lines = newestText.split("\n");
          const lastItem = lines[lines.length - 1];
          const priceSplit = lastItem.split(";");
          const price = priceSplit[1];
          const modifiedPrice = price.replace(",", ".");
          const modifiedPriceInt = parseFloat(modifiedPrice, 10);
          totalPrice += modifiedPriceInt;
          totalPrice = Math.round((totalPrice + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
          Cookies.set("priceCookie", totalPrice, {
            expires: 1
          });
          priceH1Child.textContent = "";
          priceH1Child.textContent = totalPrice + " €";
        }
      });

      // Price cookie, retrieves the last displayed price after refreshing
      const cookie = Cookies.get("priceCookie");
      const cookieInt = parseFloat(cookie, 10);
      if (cookieInt != 0) {
        priceH1Child.textContent = cookie + " €";
        totalPrice = cookieInt;
      }

      // A return button that removes the latest added product
      returnButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        console.log('works');

        // Subtracting price of a removed item
        const currentText = textArea.value;
        const lines = currentText.split("\n");
        const lastItem = lines[lines.length - 1];
        const priceSplit = lastItem.split(";");
        const price = priceSplit[1];
        const modifiedPrice = price.replace(",", ".");
        const modifiedPriceInt = parseFloat(modifiedPrice, 10);
        totalPrice -= modifiedPriceInt;
        totalPrice = Math.round((totalPrice + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
        priceH1Child.textContent = totalPrice + " €";
        Cookies.set("priceCookie", totalPrice, {
          expires: 1
        });

        // Removes last product after pressing the return button
        lines.pop(); // Remove the last line
        textArea.value = lines.join("\n");
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading CSV files:", error);
    }
  });

  // Select All button functionality
  function checkAll() {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox"]');
    if (allCheckbox.checked == true) {
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
      }
    } else if (allCheckbox.checked == false) {
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
  }

  // After checking a certain checkbox it modifies the csvFiles array
  function applyChanges() {
    const kauflandCheckbox = document.getElementById("kaufland");
    const tescoCheckbox = document.getElementById("tesco");

    // Adding into array if the checkboxes are checked
    if (tescoCheckbox.checked == true && kauflandCheckbox.checked == true) {
      csvFiles = ["results_kaufland.csv", "results_tesco.csv"];
    } else if (kauflandCheckbox.checked == true) {
      csvFiles = ["results_kaufland.csv"];
    } else if (tescoCheckbox.checked == true) {
      csvFiles = ["results_tesco.csv"];
    }

    // Removing from array if the checkboxes arent checked
    if (tescoCheckbox.checked == false && kauflandCheckbox.checked == false) {
      csvFiles = [];
    } else if (tescoCheckbox.checked == false) {
      csvFiles = ["results_kaufland.csv"];
    } else if (kauflandCheckbox.checked == false) {
      csvFiles = ["results_tesco.csv"];
    }

    // Fething the promises from csvFiles array
    fetchPromises = csvFiles.map((url) =>
      fetch(url).then((response) => response.text())
    );
  }

  // Parsing the data from .csv file, in order to be separated in rows
  function parseCSVData(csvData) {
    const rows = csvData.split("\n");
    return rows.map((row) => row.trim());
  }

  // Function that filters and sorts the suggestions based on price
  function getAutocompleteSuggestions(inputText, autocompleteData) {
    const inputWords = removeDiacritics(inputText.toLowerCase()).split(" ");
    const matchingSuggestions = autocompleteData.filter((suggestion) => {
      const suggestionWords = removeDiacritics(suggestion.toLowerCase()).split(
        " "
      );
      return inputWords.every((inputWord) =>
        suggestionWords.some((suggestionWord) =>
          suggestionWord.startsWith(inputWord)
        )
      );
    });

    // Sort the suggestions based on price (ascending order)
    const sortedSuggestions = matchingSuggestions.sort((a, b) => {
      const priceA = parseFloat(a.split(";")[1].replace(",", ".").trim());
      const priceB = parseFloat(b.split(";")[1].replace(",", ".").trim());
      let ranking = priceA - priceB;

      if (selectedValue == 'lowest-highest') {
        ranking = priceA - priceB;
      } else if (selectedValue == 'highest-lowest') {
        ranking = priceB - priceA;
      }

      return ranking;
    });

    return sortedSuggestions;
  }

  // Function used to render all the suggestions into the roll down window
  function renderSuggestions(suggestions) {
    suggestionsContainer.innerHTML = "";

    if (suggestions.length > 0) {
      suggestions.forEach((suggestion) => {
        const suggestionElement = document.createElement("div");
        suggestionElement.classList.add("autocomplete-suggestion");
        suggestionElement.textContent = suggestion;
        suggestionsContainer.appendChild(suggestionElement);
      });
      suggestionsContainer.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      suggestionsContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  // Function to remove diacritics from a string
  function removeDiacritics(text) {
    return text.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
  }
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'intro';
  src: url('fonts/Intro-Trial-Rg.ttf');
}

html {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #e7ecea;
}

.name {
  font-family: intro;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.desc {
  font-family: intro;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  color: #74777b;
}

.github {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: .5%;
}

.link_github {
  font-family: intro;
  font-size: 110%;
  padding-left: .5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4299e1;
}

.link_github:hover {
  color: #74777b;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  font-family: intro;
  background-color: white;
  height: 7%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #e7ecea;
  border-bottom: 0.5rem solid transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2CC185;
  padding-right: 6%;
  padding-left: 6%;
  font-size: 150%;
  transition: border-bottom 0.3s linear;
}

#tab_last {
  border-right: 1px solid #e7ecea;
}

.tab:hover {
  color: #74777b;
}

.tab:hover .icon {
  stroke: #74777b;
}

.tab.active {
  border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #2CC185;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}

#tab1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.search {
  width: 23rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
}

.textarea {
  position: relative;
  top: -22.5rem;
  left: 35rem;
  width: 23rem;
  height: 37rem;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  padding: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.checkboxes {
  position: relative;
  left: 24rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.checkbox-item {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.apply_changes {
  width: 9rem;
  height: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: #2CC185;
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.apply_changes:hover {
  color: #666981;
}

.apply_changes:active {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.kaufland,
.tesco,
.all {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -50rem;
  left: 60rem;
}

.dropbtn {
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 13rem;
}

.dropbtn span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropbtn span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropbtn:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.dropbtn:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 13rem;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.autocomplete .autocomplete-suggestions {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 384px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  top: 80%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  --tw-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 4px 6px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 10px 15px -3px var(--tw-shadow-color), 0 4px 6px -4px var(--tw-shadow-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}

.autocomplete .autocomplete-suggestion {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete .autocomplete-suggestion:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.return_button {
  position: relative;
  left: 54rem;
  top: 0rem;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.return_button:active {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.price {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Price Saver</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css">
  <script src="tabs.js"></script>
  <script src="script_web.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="github">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon_github" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2c3e50" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
          <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
          <path d="M5.315 2.1c.791 -.113 1.9 .145 3.333 .966l.272 .161l.16 .1l.397 -.083a13.3 13.3 0 0 1 4.59 -.08l.456 .08l.396 .083l.161 -.1c1.385 -.84 2.487 -1.17 3.322 -1.148l.164 .008l.147 .017l.076 .014l.05 .011l.144 .047a1 1 0 0 1 .53 .514a5.2 5.2 0 0 1 .397 2.91l-.047 .267l-.046 .196l.123 .163c.574 .795 .93 1.728 1.03 2.707l.023 .295l.007 .272c0 3.855 -1.659 5.883 -4.644 6.68l-.245 .061l-.132 .029l.014 .161l.008 .157l.004 .365l-.002 .213l-.003 3.834a1 1 0 0 1 -.883 .993l-.117 .007h-6a1 1 0 0 1 -.993 -.883l-.007 -.117v-.734c-1.818 .26 -3.03 -.424 -4.11 -1.878l-.535 -.766c-.28 -.396 -.455 -.579 -.589 -.644l-.048 -.019a1 1 0 0 1 .564 -1.918c.642 .188 1.074 .568 1.57 1.239l.538 .769c.76 1.079 1.36 1.459 2.609 1.191l.001 -.678l-.018 -.168a5.03 5.03 0 0 1 -.021 -.824l.017 -.185l.019 -.12l-.108 -.024c-2.976 -.71 -4.703 -2.573 -4.875 -6.139l-.01 -.31l-.004 -.292a5.6 5.6 0 0 1 .908 -3.051l.152 -.222l.122 -.163l-.045 -.196a5.2 5.2 0 0 1 .145 -2.642l.1 -.282l.106 -.253a1 1 0 0 1 .529 -.514l.144 -.047l.154 -.03z" stroke-width="0" fill="currentColor" />
        </svg>
    <a class="link_github" href="https://github.com/Adam-Simon1/Price-Saver">Open my repository</a>
  </div>

  <div class="name">
    <h1>Price Saver</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="desc">
    <h2>Uses informantion from the shops sites and chooses the best price for you.</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab active" onclick="changeTab(event, 'tab1')">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2CC185" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <path d="M5 12l-2 0l9 -9l9 9l-2 0" />
                <path d="M5 12v7a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-7" />
                <path d="M9 21v-6a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v6" />
              </svg> Home
    </div>
    <div class="tab" onclick="changeTab(event, 'tab2')">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2CC185" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <path d="M9.615 20h-2.615a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8" />
                <path d="M14 19l2 2l4 -4" />
                <path d="M9 8h4" />
                <path d="M9 12h2" />
              </svg> Shopping List
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_last" onclick="changeTab(event, 'tab3')">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2CC185" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <path d="M3 7l6 -3l6 3l6 -3l0 13l-6 3l-6 -3l-6 3l0 -13" />
                <path d="M9 4l0 13" />
                <path d="M15 7l0 13" />
              </svg> Map
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab1" class="tab-content active">
    <div class="autocomplete">
      <input class="search" id="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Type something...">
      <div class="autocomplete-suggestions"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-id">
      <div class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="kaufland" class="kaufland" value="kaufland">
        <label for="kaufland" class="label">Kaufland</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="tesco" class="tesco" value="tesco">
        <label for="tesco" class="label">Tesco</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxall" id="all" class="all" value="all">
        <label for="all" class="label">All</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button class="apply_changes" id="apply-changes">Apply Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="textarea_div">
      <textarea class="textarea" name="ListField" id="list-field" cols="30" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button class="return_button" id="button-input">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon-arrow" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#74777b" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
              <path d="M9.586 4l-6.586 6.586a2 2 0 0 0 0 2.828l6.586 6.586a2 2 0 0 0 2.18 .434l.145 -.068a2 2 0 0 0 1.089 -1.78v-2.586h7a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-4l-.005 -.15a2 2 0 0 0 -1.995 -1.85l-7 -.001v-2.585a2 2 0 0 0 -3.414 -1.414z" stroke-width="0" fill="currentColor" />
            </svg>
          </button>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <h1 id="price-h1" class="price">Price: <span></span></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><span>Select the price </span></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a data-value="lowest-highest">Lowest to Highest</a>
        <a data-value="highest-lowest">Highest to Lowest</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
    <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
    <p>This is the content of Tab 2.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
    <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
    <p>This is the content of Tab 3.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried writing the code inside dev tools console and it worked.

[image].

The thing is I used this code on a testing website, where I didn't really bother with styling. And it worked there. The element ids and classes are the same.

I tried rearranging the divs, but didn't work either.

All of the elements work, except this one.

Comment: What does the browser console have to say? Where did you put this JS code - does the element already exist at that point? Your issue might simply be the same as explained here, [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1427878)

Comment: Please put your code in a snippet demo using the editor so it's more clear what the problem might be. As CBroe stated, we have no idea how you're implementing the script. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: it works with just the little code you provided

Comment: Change the snippet I made you to a [mcve]

Comment: Is the `returnButton.addEventListener` meant to be inside the event listener for `applyChangesButton`?

Answer (score 0):

One thread to investigate: a `click` event isn't a single event, it's a composition of `mousedown` and `mouseup` events *on the same target.* And those two are separated by at least some milliseconds, during which the page - and what's directly under the cursor - can change.

Which means: if on `mousedown` something happens with the screen layout and `mouseup` has a different target (e.g. the original button is covered by some overlay), then `click` doesn't happen.

You can verify whether that's the case here by replacing `element.addEventListener("click", //...` with `element.addEventListener("mousedown", //...`